# Formal proof for simple set problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm having trouble formalizing a proof for what I feel like is obviously true.

We have finite sets $x_1,x_2$, such that $|x_1|≤|x_2|$ and are subsets of a larger set $S$.

Prove (or disprove) that if:
$$min(|x_1|,|x_2|)=|x_1 \cap x_2|$$ is true, then
$$x_1=x_1\cap x_2$$
and does this imply that $x_1$ is a subset of $x_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x_1 = 2\mathbb{Z}$ (the even numbers) and $x_2 = 3 \mathbb{Z}$ (the multiples of 3) as subsets of $S = \mathbb{Z}$.

The intersection is $x_1 \cap x_2 = 6 \mathbb{Z}$ (the multiples of 6).

All these sets have the same cardinality, yet $x_1 \ne x_1 \cap x_2$ (so $x_1$ is also not a subset of $x_2$).

**EDIT:** Now the question has been changed to finite sets only. Because $|x_1| \le |x_2|$, we are forced to have 
$$|x_1| = \text{min}\{|x_1|,|x_2|\} = |x_1 \cap x_2|.$$
But $x_1 \cap x_2 \subseteq x_1$, so the above equality of cardinalities then forces $x_1 = x_1 \cap x_2$. This also means $x_1 \subseteq x_2$, because any element of $x_1$ also belongs to $x_1 \cap x_2$, i.e. to $x_1$ *and* $x_2$.

Comment: I understand your counterargument. But I was considering finite sets only. (Didn't put that in the question).

Comment: Okay, well, it must be now that $|x_1| = |x_1 \cap x_2|$. Since you have an injection from $x_1 \cap x_2$ to $x_1$ just by inclusion, and the sets are finite of same cardinality, this is a bijection, i.e. the sets are equal as desired. It also implies $x_1 \subseteq x_2$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I can see how $|x_1 \cap x_2| \subset |x_1|$ forces $x_1 \cap x_2 = x_1$. But how can this be formally shown, other than just saying the equality of the cardinalities forces that to be true (Is there a basic theorem or relation i'm missing?)

Comment: The following is a basic (important) fact about finite sets: If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets of the same size, then any injection or surjection between them is a bijection. It's worth trying to prove that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have $|x_1| = |x_1 \cap x_2|$ and $x_1 \cap x_2 \subset x_1$.

If there was some $z \in x_1$ such that $z \notin x_1 \cap x_2 $, then
$|x_1| > |x_1 \cap x_2|$, hence $x_1 \subset x_1 \cap x_2$.

For the last question, if $z \in x_1$ then $z \in x_1 \cap x_2 \subset x_2.$ Hence $x_1 \subset x_2$.